# How do I add JS and CSS to WP (Flatsome)

Tags: css, javascript

I have a codepen that I would like to import into my WP setup. It is an expanding column layout, which includes custom CSS and JS. Link here: https://codepen.io/thedonquixotic/pen/WGYXyd

Now, I have tried a few different ways, latest being that I used the plugin WP Coder: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-coder/

I followed instructions, whish is to upload the JS and CSS file through admin panel, and then using the plugin to include the uploaded files, as well as uploaded the html. When I call the div id as per instructions, absolutely nothing happens. http://oriyadigital.co.za/test-1/

I had instances where the CSS and HTML displayes correctly, but never the JS yet.

Please can you give me the "Dummies guide to" for this?

Comment: Well, normally you'd ofcourse include the code in the js/css files of the theme. If you're not the developer you need to create a child theme to ensure your code only adds to the theme and doesn't break with any updates. https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Styles and scripts in WP are 'enqueued' \(normally in functions.php)
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Comment: Hi, Thank you for this. I have created a child theme for flatsome, called Oriya. I have queued both the CSS and JS file in functions.php, with no result. I then though I might be doing it wrong, and downloaded the plugin, WP Coder. This supposedly does the include as well. I followed the instructions as they set out, and I still cannot get this to work correctly.

Comment: Welcome to WPSE! Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/312288/edit) to include the code you've added to your theme; specifically, how you "queued both the CSS and JS file in functions.php". That'll help us diagnose any possible issues, and allow us to better help you.

Comment: @PatJ, sorry about that, still very new here. I tried getting the code to paste it here, but I am getting a 500 error now. Since the project is a learning curve for me, and I havent been able to do much, would it be worth starting from scratch, under guidance of developers that could guide me? I have installed a theme, flatsome, and created a child theme under that. I am unsure if this might be playing with the outcomes?

Comment: Enqueue your style and js in child theme functions.php https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/ more about it https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-properly-add-javascripts-and-styles-in-wordpress/

Comment: I usually do this, check the source to see where it’s being loaded in the page and if there are conflicts, adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

In theme options there is usually an area to put that as well.  Maybe under advanced.  Look around in the theme options section, not just wordpress options.